# c# Selenium Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

```
ChromeDriver drv1;
drv1 = new ChromeDriver(co);
drv1.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://accounts.google.com/signin");
```

i get this error when logging in google, I cannot log into any accounts.
Please help me 
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try allowing less secured apps on your google account. Make sure you don't have 2-factor authentication enabled cause it won't work with that on. You can find this option here: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: it didn't work , I still can't log in from any same account.

I tried another computer, another account ,the result is the same